# What's the path of a character from keyboard to application in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, stdio, keycode

There was an article in a 1980s computer magazine (Kilobaud? Creative Computing?) that described how a key press emits a key code, how it gets passed through a device driver, translated to an ASCII code, send through an event handler, blah blah blah and ultimately ends up as a byte (or whatever) received by an application via stdin (or some equivalent).  What the application did with it was outside the scope of the article. The article was interesting, more for showing the complexity of operating systems and device drivers of that time than for technical practicality.

Now in 2010 we have Linux with a very large kernel, loadable modules, layers of unixey tty thingies and pipes and multiprocessing... is there a similar article published anywhere that traces a character from keyboard to some app's stdin, describing every step of the way?

Looking for something technical (not watered down to pop science magazine level) but understandable by non-experts at kernels and low level IO workings.

(If there is no such article, go ahead and write one, post it as an answer here!)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google brought up this:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1080

Its from 1995, but not much has changed from the perspective you want (not at source code level)